# Span element becomes misaligned when adding other elements

Tags: html, css, css-float, inline, vertical-alignment

Please refer -  https://jsfiddle.net/59a15a9d/

```css
span {
  height: 200px;
  width:200px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 4px;
  /*float: left*/ /*Second uncomment this*/
}
```

```html
<span>hello</span>
<span>hello
<!-- <p>asd</p> --> <!-- first uncomment this -->
</span>
```

I have 2 span elements vertically aligned with "inline-block" CSS.
Now in the JSFiddle follow the comments. I have a few questions:

1. When you remove the first comment, you add a `<p>` element inside the 2nd span and then the 1st span automatically is misaligned. Why?
2. Vertical-align property will fix it. How?
3. When you remove the second comment, instead of a vertical align it just floats `<span>` left and again they are aligned correctly. What magic did float have on the spans?

Not related to above, one more quick question.

When position absolute/fixed is added to a span element, why does it become a block element?

Comment: You should not that you can't put a `p` tag inside a span...it's invalid HTML.

Comment: If you don't understand basic HTML structure and CSS layout this is not the place to come for tutorials.

Comment: We're all moderators on SO. Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

> Not related to above, one more quick question. When position absolute/fixed is added to span element, why does it become a block element?

The browser think that it doesn't need any relative measurement again *as it uses absolute/fixed position*, so all surroundings item will be ignored.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13329826)

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft - This is not a new question, Kekesed was quoting the last question in the post. This answer only answers that part but it is not a new question.

Comment: yup, i was quoting a question from his. Thank you for edit, Nisse hhehehe

Answer (score 0):

*When you remove the first comment, you add a `<p>` element inside the 2nd span and then the 1st span automatically is misaligned. Why?*

Paulie_D's comment is right. From the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3)

> Generally, block-level elements may contain inline elements and other
>   block-level elements. Generally, **inline elements may contain only data
>   and other inline elements**. Inherent in this structural distinction is
>   the idea that block elements create "larger" structures than inline
>   elements...Generally, **block-level elements begin on new lines**, inline elements do not.

When you add a paragraph element, it's creating a new line. Note that if you remove the CSS making the spans an inline-block (the inline-block style and the float), the paragraph is placed *after* the span tag on a new line, not inside of it.

*Vertical-align property will fix it. How?*

It doesn't, at least not for all values for vertical-align.

[W3C Wiki Page for Vertical-Align](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align)

The values top, bottom, text-top, and text-bottom "fix" it. But the values baseline, super, sub, inherit, length, and percentage values do not. I don't think you can expect normal behavior of CSS on invalid HTML.

*What magic did float have on the spans?*

[W3C Wiki Page for Float Property:](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/float)

> The element **generates a *block* box** that is floated to the left. Content flows on the right side of the box, starting at the top.

The float fixes things by making the spans block-level elements, which are allowed to contain other block level elements.